# I liked it at school yesterday very much

Tags: word-order

I have gotten confused with word order. If we have **"time"** it goes at the end:

***I came in the evening***

If we have **"place"** it goes at the end, too

***I came to school***

If we have them both firstly goes **"place"**, then **"time"**

***I came to school yesterday***

What if we have also some adverb - **"late"**

***I came to school in the evening late***

Such a word order or a different one?

Actually originally I got stuck with **"very much"**. I had a sentence like

***I liked it at school yesterday very much***

We can have a context

*Yesterday there were a lot of places we visited. We had a party in a club, a park, a forest and even at school.*

And someone asks:

*Where did you like it yesterday very much? I ... mmm, I have forgotten, sorry!*

Of course the person can answer shortly -**"at school"**, but we are interested in the full answer:

***I liked it at school yesterday very much***

Yes, we can also say

***Yesterday I liked it at school very much***

But what if we place **"yesterday"** in the second part of the sentence, not in the first one?

What are your thoughts about it, guys?:)

Answer (score 1):

All of the following are perfectly idiomatic:

> - I enjoyed school today very much.
> - I really enjoyed school today.
> - I enjoyed school a lot today.
> - I really enjoyed today's lessons.

The word order isn't strictly dictated by a rule about where the "time", or the superlative goes. It depends on the idiomatic usage of different words and phrases, and to a degree, what you are emphasising.

Answer (score 0):

> **I liked it very much at school yesterday**.
>
> **Yesterday I liked it very much  at school.**
>
> **I liked it yesterday very much at school**
>
> **At school I liked it very much yesterday**.

I think all the above sentences are correct and it is a matter of choice.

> **He came early to school**.
>
> **He came to school late.**
>
> **He came late to school**.
>
> **He came to school early**.

I think all the structures are possible.

It is a matter of choice.